# Browse Image Functionality in Selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

How can I automate browse and add image functionality in any website/application so that I can execute the add image functionality in Selenium.

I have tried to navigate to any random application and I tried to automate the click add image button present in the navigated website, but I'm unable to automate the add image functionality on that website.

Can you please help me by providing solution to automate the add image functionality in any application/website?